# Basic jQuery Slider (bjqs) responsiveness issues

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I'm working with this [Basic jQuery Slider](http://basic-slider.com/) (bjqs) and trying to get it to work responsively. Their changelog says the responsiveness of it is in "beta", so I'm guessing that's why it's kind of flakey.

Here's the url to the slider I'm implementing: http://test.hetzelcreative.com/hybrid/

There are basically two issues with it & they both have to do with loading the page at a small screen size (mobile phone width):

1. The images don't load proportionately and aren't fitting 100%
2. When you resize the browser up, the positioning gets all messed up and it even starts to duplicate the images and stack them vertically. A page refresh fixes this, but of course that's not acceptable

Also, in `bjqs-1.3.min.js` I have the width set to 854px and height to 481px. It was originally set to 400x300 or something. I'm wondering if this is the source of my problem. If I remove those w & h attributes though the whole thing doesn't work.

Comment: seems okay on latest version of Chrome (v25), Win 7

Comment: Resize your browser all the way down, then do a refresh. You should see the proportion issue, and then if you resize up, you'll see things start to get even more messed up.

Comment: @Trevan I did as you suggested, but I'm still not seeing the issue you are getting in Chrome. Mostly beta, because getting it to work cross-browser is always an issue, and takes time to work out the bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I've got similiar problem (about resizing up browser window) - but finally I've fixed it (or hack, You name it):

When You initialize the plugin, You can define dimensions (e.g. `width`) of the slider - and You should there put the largest possible value, because it will be the *maximum* size of single slide on Your page (shame that official documentation doesn't describe it this way) - so it should be Your (device) screen size:

```
width: window.screen.width,
```

and don't forget to make it responsive:

```
responsive: true,
```

and after initialization of the slider (it can be placed in the end of the document) You should trigger `resize` event to resize Your slider to current browser size (because if window won't be maximized slider will be bigger than it and not visible in 100%):

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

It works for me on newest firefox & chrome - not tested on IE & other stuff.

PS. In case if You are using slider pagination bullets and You want to keep them centered horizontally You should add this code before triggering resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('yourSliderId .bjqs-markers.h-centered').css({'left':0});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I gave this a try in a few different browsers. I'd say it has more than one or two small bugs when it comes to responsiveness.

Instead of trying to fix all of the problems bjqs has have you considered looking for one that was designed for responsiveness from the start instead?

- **[SequenceJS](http://www.sequencejs.com/)**, looks very active and has a large github following
- **[FlexSlider](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider)**, also has a large github following but the issues list looks a little long depending on which browsers you are targeting/etc

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue where I got everything working responsively, except for the initial load on a smaller screen, like a smart phone. You could see the problem in my browser when I shrunk the screen down. It would be fixed when I resized the window though. It just would not work on the initial load.

I found a fix that worked for me. I grabbed the un-minified version of the bjqs-1.3.js and made a quick addition. Line 175 started out like this:

```
var conf_responsive = function() {
```

Then there is an `if` statement within that function that say this:

```
if(settings.animtype === 'slide'){
```

I put something inside THAT `if` statement, because my animation type was 'slide.' You may have to do something similar for the `if(settings.animtype === 'fade'){` conditional if you're using fade.

But anyway, inside that if conditional, beneath the `$(window).resize(function() {})`, I called it like so:

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
$(window).trigger('resize'); 
 }
);
```

That seems to have fixed the issue I was having. Not sure this is the exact same problem that was posted here, but it might help someone looking for a solution to a related problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting the width of your slider class to match that of the max-width of the plugin.

i.e. in this case you have it at 100%, it should be 854px.

Then add `overflow:hidden;` to the slider class so you don't get the stack effect you talk about.

Comment: But see I want the previous and next images to be visible too. Adding overflow:hidden makes the previous and next images not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked in depth at the script due to time restraints. However, what I would do is make sure the script is in a wrapper with a set width & height. Then set the script to 100% width and the height to 100%.

Comment: Problem is, the width is 100% of the body, so that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

To fix the width problem you can get the container div width in the initalization:

```
$(function () {
    $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
        animtype: 'slide',
        height: 445,
        width: $("#banner-slide").width(),
        responsive: true,
        randomstart: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who look for the solution, here it is :

take the solution above to fix the width problem

for the height problem, just apply a x factor existing between the height and the width

example : if your slider images are twice larger than longer then apply this :

```
$(function () {
    $('#banner-slide').bjqs({
        animtype: 'slide',
        width: $("#banner-slide").width(),
        height: $("#banner-slide").width() /2,
        responsive: true,
        randomstart: true
    });
});
```